# Is there a simple and yet nice looking GUI library for a C program?

Tags: c, linux, user-interface, open-source

I program mostly in C while studying at university. I was wondering if there is some simple open-source library that would let me make a GUI for a program in C.

Things to concider by priority:

1. Simple
2. Nice-looking
3. Features

**I don't know how to program in C++ and would prefer to stay in pure C.**

Answer (score 5):

i would highly recommend Glade + GTK.

i use it in combination with python, and it works quite well.
it's also very simple to use.

here is an example:

http://people.gnome.org/~newren/tutorials/developing-with-gnome/html/apc.html#libglade-example-1

hope that helps!

EDIT:

here is a more extensive tutorial:

http://www.micahcarrick.com/gtk-glade-tutorial-part-1.html

Comment: Not sure about items 1 & 3, but it fails item 2 for me!  ;-)

Comment: I think GTK is the only option for pure C. +1'd.

Comment: @David hmm? i don't understand your comment.

Comment: I don't think GTK is good-looking. You still get an up-vote because I don't think there is any other plausible option.

Comment: That's a strange assessment, GTP is highly skinnable, you can make it look pretty much like anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

However, notice that it might be difficult to write GUI code in C which runs on many different systems (e.g. on Linux, MacOSX, Android, and Windows). Gtk claim to have such a goal, but I don't know if it fully reached.

Comment: And you usually design a program to have a GUI. Adding a GUI to a command line program might be not very simple (because GUI & Web applications are centered around an event loop).